# useEffect is re-rendering whole component every time

Tags: reactjs

`useEffect` re-rendering whole component constantly. But, I just want to update `showNav` value. How can I achieve that?

```js
  const showNav = useSelector((state: any) => state.global.showNav);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log("updaing");

 useEffect(() => {
    const scrl = document.querySelector("#scroller");
    let previousPosition = 0;
    
    scrl?.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
      if (scrl.scrollTop > previousPosition) {
        previousPosition = scrl.scrollTop;
        console.log("Not Showing navbar");
        dispatch(setShowNav(false));
      } else {
        console.log("Showing nav");
        dispatch(setShowNav(true));
        previousPosition = scrl.scrollTop;
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is `useEffect` causing the component to re-render?  Or, far more likely, is *the scroll event* causing the component to re-render?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  What exactly is the problem, does the page become unusable from the re-renders in some way?  In what way is this not working as expected?

Comment: You want update only when `showNav` value changes?

Comment: Yes I just want to update `showNav` but without `console.log("updating")` print.

Comment: @PrimerCielo: *"but without console.log("updating") print"* - Then remove the `console.log` statement?

Comment: No. I mean why the the whole component will be re-rendered? why not just inside `useEffect` updating `showNav`?

Comment: @PrimerCielo: Because when state is updated any component using that state is re-rendered.  Again, what's the actual problem?  What isn't working here?

Comment: I have data to fetch if the whole component updating continuously then continuous fetch request call.

Comment: @PrimerCielo: The code shown has no `fetch` operation.  And if *some other code* that you're not showing is performing a `fetch` operation on every render, you should probably correct that because there's no need to perform a `fetch` operation on every render.  Only perform it (1) when the component first loads or (2) when specific state changes.  You can use `useEffect` to control that.

Comment: So, its normal for `useEffect` to re-render whole component every time when a state changed?

Comment: @PrimerCielo: No, it's normal for *state changes* to re-render the component.  Because that's exactly how React works.  It has nothing to do with `useEffect`.

Comment: Can I ask ? I have worked with Vuejs in there I have encountered `onMounted` hook. But, that not re-render whole component when a state changed. So, `useEffect` is completely different? can I achieve same thing with react?

Comment: @PrimerCielo: `useEffect` with an empty dependency array will only execute once, when the component is first loaded.  If you re-load the component from higher up the component hierarchy, then it'll run again.  However, in the code shown, there is exactly zero evidence indicating that your `useEffect` is running multiple times.  None.  Because when your `useEffect` runs, it produces no output.  What it *does* do is attach an event handler for a scroll event.  That event handler updates state.  State updates re-render a component.  None of this is a problem, you're just assuming it is.

Comment: Thank you. I just thinking I did wrong, and it's issuing performance but app is running well. I assume because In vuejs the same thing I did there is not running outer code of `onMounted`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this useEffect is the one re-rendering the component

Comment: Hi, this would be better suited as a comment as it doesn't help to solve OP's issue.

Comment: wasn't able to make a comment